# How to extract multiple correlating variables from a JSon

Tags: json, jmeter, json-path-expression, json-extract

I have to extract multiple correlating variables from a response (which is json) in JMeter. Part of the response is listed below:

```
[
  {
    "data": {
      "id": "efaa6876-7a8d-4723-9d85-1ed99e822f06",
      "type": "courses",
      "attributes": {
        "created-at": "2019-02-07T16:38:50.735Z",
        "contents-count": 267,
        "units": [
          {
            "id": "31b5fcb1-24ee-441e-a0ee-ca859fc9a89d",
            "position": null,
            "progress": 0,
            "completed": false,
            "show_name": false,
            "node_id": "1",
            "children": [
              {
                "id": "b8ed75a3-0390-4273-82c3-03ee6eba729c",
                "position": null,
                "image": null,
                "progress": 0,
                "completed": false,
                "show_name": true,
                "node_id": "2",
                "children": [],
                "contents": [
                  {
                    "id": "fa1bdc2f-4330-425c-9c10-3734d07125aa",
                    "link": {
                      "url": "#",
                      "target": "_blank",
                      "class": "learning-object-link",
                      "data": {
                        "id": "fa1bdc2f-4330-425c-9c10-3734d07125aa",
                        "user-role": "teacher",
                        "open-method-tablet": "newtab",
                        "open-method-desktop": "modal",
                        "content-open-method": null,
                        "modal-size-method": "fully_responsive",
                        "fixed-width": null,
                        "fixed-height": null,
                        "aspect-ratio": null
                      }
                    },
                    "is_work": false,
                    "is_fun": false,
                    "completed": false,
                    "total_activities": 2,
                    "completed_activities": 0,
                    "progress": 0,
                    "updated_at": false,
                    "attempts": 0,
                    "duration": null
                  },
                  {
                    "id": "ceceabfd-5151-4656-af5d-3392c5a4c04c",
                      "link": {
                      "url": "#",
                      "target": "_blank",
                      "class": "learning-object-link",
                      "data": {
                        "id": "ceceabfd-5151-4656-af5d-3392c5a4c04c",
                        "user-role": "teacher",
                        "open-method-tablet": "newtab",
                        "open-method-desktop": "modal",
                        "content-open-method": null,
                        "modal-size-method": "fully_responsive",
                        "fixed-width": null,
                        "fixed-height": null,
                        "aspect-ratio": null
                      }
                    },
                    "is_work": false,
                    "is_fun": false,
                    "completed": false,
                    "total_activities": 2,
                    "completed_activities": 0,
                    "progress": 0,
                    "updated_at": false,
                    "attempts": 0,
                    "duration": null
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "id": "60639cbd-f872-492d-b8e9-db83f8789fcf",
                "position": null,
                "image": null,
                "progress": 0,
                "completed": false,
                "show_name": true,
                "node_id": "3",
                "children": [],
                "contents": [
                  {
                    "id": "1825f834-7099-4bb4-b7a2-fc634faffc86",
                      "link": {
                      "url": "#",
                      "target": "_blank",
                      "class": "learning-object-link",
                      "data": {
                        "id": "1825f834-7099-4bb4-b7a2-fc634faffc86",
                        "user-role": "teacher",
                        "open-method-tablet": "newtab",
                        "open-method-desktop": "modal",
                        "content-open-method": null,
                        "modal-size-method": "fully_responsive",
                        "fixed-width": null,
                        "fixed-height": null,
                        "aspect-ratio": null
                      }
                    },
```

To proceed with the next request, I have to extract unit id (e.g. 31b5fcb1-24ee-441e-a0ee-ca859fc9a89d), children id (e.g. b8ed75a3-0390-4273-82c3-03ee6eba729c) and contents id (e.g. fa1bdc2f-4330-425c-9c10-3734d07125aa). There are several units, each unit has several children and each children has several contents. Each content id matches just one children id and each children id matches just one unit id. Ids have to be selected on a random basis.

I've tried to extract all ids from the response and use them randomly, but it doesn't work this way.

Comment: I think I should extract unit id first, and then using this value to extract children id. When I'm trying to extract unit id, all ids are extracted - unit ids, children ids, and contents ids. How to extract just unit ids without any children ids?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extract only Unit Ids, you can use following JSON Path Expressions:

```
$..data.attributes.units[?(@.id)].id
```

Random Value for Unit Id also can be extracted using JMeter JSON Extractor:

[image]

Comment: Sure could you please accept this is an answer and upvote.

Comment: I'm afraid my reputation is too low to do that :( I'm getting the following message: Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.